# php doesn't display error

Tags: php, pdo, webserver

I just updated the php version from 5.6 to 7.0, and I noticed that some thing not working as well, for example the error.

I just edited my php.ini file and set:

```
 display_errors = On
 display_startup_errors = On
```

I've rebooted the apache2 service, also rebooted the webserver entire but same problem the error of my application aren't displayed.
There is something on PDO that doesn't working 'cause I get a blank web page after declare the connection string, but I don't know which not working 'cause no error is displayed.

In my app I also added this code line:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

not working also.

I check in phpinfo() if the display_error is enabled, and yes, are both enabled.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

It once worked for me instead of

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Make a file phpinfo.php and put it in your directory. Put this content in it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then go to it in the browser:

```
[yourserver]/[yoursite]/phpinfo.php
```

If this page displays properly, great, find this entry in it:

```
error_log
```

This is how you will find the path for the php log.

Comment: Check your PHP logs. Which PHP are you using? XAMPP, LAMP stack, MAMP.....? If you use XAMPP, go to [XAMPP folder]/var/log/ and look any files in there, specifically php_error.log

Comment: I'm using LAMP, in which folder the log is located?

Comment: Go "cd /var/logs" or "cd /var/log" and do "ls" there.

Comment: I just clean the apache2 folder, reload the page that is blank but no file is created

Comment: Please see my edited answer to learn how to use phpinfo() for all of your troubles :)

Comment: Problem fixed, was pdo that missing.. but is strange that the error isn't displayed, just discovered now that phpmyadmin also is broken..

Comment: Glad you resolved it. Upvotes on any on my comment or answer is appreciated :)

Comment: Try using the method I told you, with the phpinfo.php (see above for detailed explanation) to see the errors in the log.

Comment: Yes, fix phpmyadmin also installing sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring, thanks for the helpp

Comment: haha, I don't know why you got the downvote, I have accepted your answer and upvoted, I can't do more of this, have nice day.

Comment: Actually, you can, by upvoting my comments, just as I have upvoted yours, and I am happy if I could help you too! No problem :)

Comment: frankly I do not care much about digital reputation, but happy to hear this :)

Comment: Yeah, well some people do, and I am one of those people. Problem is, when you run out of reputation, you cannot ask questions any more. And a lot of people give you negative (downvote your questions), and cause your reputation to decrease. This causes you to not be able to post questions. This is why digital reputation is important.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write in `.htaccess` file follow line:

```
php_flag display_errors 1
```